# Delete documents in Lucene that do no exist

Tags: indexing, lucene, document, delete-file

I have a Lucene index created, and I would like to know how to delete the file index entries that do not already exist on the computer.
Is there any way from Lucene or have to go file by file opening a file, and by checking for java?

Edited:

The example is as follows: I have a directory which contains indexed by lucene 5 files, when I delete a file physically, I want to update the index to be removed that record lucene index. What I know is raising the logic to get you started, or if Lucene brings some option to do it automatically.

Comment: Please, explain it in a better way, perhaps using an example.

Comment: I have the same need: a big index (20h00 to create) and I wish update it because some indexed files has been removed.

Comment: In Java 7 you could the new filesystem watching features...

Comment: you could use, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If a file corresponds to a Lucene document, you can delete that document in Lucene which removes that file from the index.